# How do I use WebdriverIO (wdio) to get the number of times an element appears?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm trying to make an interaction test for my javascript code using WebdriverIO (wdio).

I want to test a delete node functionality by checking the number of times a selector appears before and after my delete function and seeing that it was decremented by one.

How do you use wdio to find the number of times a selector appears on a page?

Answer (score 5):

There is an `elements` command called in the api for the browser object.

you can use it thus:

`browser.elements(selector).value.length`

Note that elements returns an object. You need to go into value to get the array.

I've also read [here](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/1710) that you can also use the shortcut to browser elements `$$` as so:

`$$(selector).length`. That didn't work for me but it might be because I'm running an older version of wdio or some random configuration issue.